# Tomcat 6 disable JSESSIONID

Tags: tomcat, cookies, webserver, jsessionid

We are using the BIG IP F5 network devices which create a cookie to maintain session stickiness to each of the servers running tomcat. Based on this can we configure Tomcat 6 to not create a JSESSIONID whether it by a cookie or writing it to the URL ????

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers
Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can't. How is tomcat suppose to manage sessions across requests? You have to implement a custom session manager in Tomcat.